# Datagridview ComboBox Databinding "Value is not valid"

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am trying to bind a DataGridViewComboBox to a list for hours now.

But a

```
"Value is not valid"-Error-Dialog is everything I get :(
```

From my local oracle-test-database I am fetching some data. Everything works fine but the combobox. I want the combobox to show the - sometimes - in the db chosen value and let the user change the value via the combobox.

I have a class called DtoPerson:

```
internal class DtoPerson
{
    private String _name;
    private Int32 _personRollenId;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Int32 PersonRollenId
    {
        get { return _personRollenId; }
        set { _personRollenId = value; }
    }
}
```

I am filling a list of DtoPersons within this method:

```
private void CreateList()
    {
        DataRow[] treiberRows = _personTable.Select("ROLLE = '2'", "PERSONNAME ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        _aufbauerListe = new List<DtoPerson>();

        if (treiberRows != null && treiberRows.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in treiberRows)
            {
                DtoPerson person = new DtoPerson();

                //Füllen der Felder
                person.Name = row["PERSONNAME"].ToString();
                int persoId;
                Int32.TryParse(row["PERSROLLID"].ToString(), out persoId);
                person.PersonRollenIdInt = (persoId > 0) ? persoId : -1;

                _aufbauerListe.Add(person);
            }
        }
    }
```

´After´ loading all data, I am Binding the ComboBox to the List:

```
(_dgvDb.Columns["AUFBAUER"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = DaPerson.Instance.AufbauerListe;
(_dgvDb.Columns["AUFBAUER"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "Name";
(_dgvDb.Columns["AUFBAUER"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "PersonRollenId";
(_dgvDb.Columns["AUFBAUER"] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataPropertyName = "AUFBAUERID";
```

Now every time i choose a value, or there should be a prechosen value, the above mentioned error is displayed. How can I solve this?

I really need help here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found my mistake:

The OracleXE send my value as an `Decimal`, a type I never heard / dreamed of...  ...now by changing the Id-Property to

```
public Decimal PersonRollenId
{
    get { return _personRollenId; }
    set { _personRollenId = value; }
}
```

everything works just fine.

It's a pitty, that DataTables don't show what kind of types they inherit...